# Node.js requests and cheerio output blank

Tags: node.js, python-requests, cheerio

I'm learning **scraping** using node.js requests and cheerio. I write a simple code to display title from a web page.

My code :

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const url = "https://singapore.craigslist.org/d/automotive-services/search/aos"

async function scrapeCraigslist() {

    try {

        const htmResult = await request.get(url);
        const $ = await cheerio.load(htmResult);
         $(".result-info").each((index, element) => {

          const title = $(element)
          .children(".result-title")
          .text();

          console.log(title);
          console.log("sk");
        
        });

    } catch (err) {

        console.error(err);
    }
}


scrapeCraigslist();
```

But when i run the code i'm getting blank nothing errors and no ouput.

Output :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Ahmed-PC\craigslist>node index.js

C:\Users\Ahmed-PC\craigslist>
```

My selection and result is coming in Chrome Developer Tools console. but not coming in node.js code

Answer (score 1):

You're using request with a promise style interface, if you wish to do this you'll need to use [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) (or you could use Axios, node-fetch etc.).

If you use request-promise your code should work fine:

**request-promise**

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const rp = require("request-promise");

const url = "https://singapore.craigslist.org/d/automotive-services/search/aos"

async function scrapeCraigslist() {

    try {

        const htmResult = await rp.get(url);
        const $ = await cheerio.load(htmResult);
        $(".result-info").each((index, element) => {

        const title = $(element)
        .children(".result-title")
        .text();

        console.log(title);
        console.log("sk");

        });

    } catch (err) {

        console.error(err);
    }
}

scrapeCraigslist();
```

**request (with callback)**

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const url = "https://singapore.craigslist.org/d/automotive-services/search/aos"

async function scrapeCraigslist() {

    request.get(url, async (error, response, htmResult) => { 
            if (error) {
                // Something went wrong
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                // The request was successful
                const $ = await cheerio.load(htmResult);
                $(".result-info").each((index, element) => {

                    const title = $(element)
                    .children(".result-title")
                    .text();

                    console.log(title);
                    console.log("sk");
                });
            }
    });

}

scrapeCraigslist();
```

Comment: Yes it worked !, Can you tell me what is the difference between request and request-promise ?

Comment: So request uses a callback interface, you pass a callback as an argument and this is called when the request completes. Request-promise is a wrapper around this module that returns a promise. IMHO, a promise type interface is easier to use. I'll add an example of using a callback passed to request as a further example!